# how to get the value of td in javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a

```
<td id="example" value="tedan!"></td>
```

How do I get the value of the td? There should be no text inside the td that is why i just put the value in the value tag.

Comment: `$('#example') .text or .html` will give the value, have a good one, cheerios!

Comment: @Tats_innit: No, `$('#example').val()` won't work.

Comment: @FelixKling cheers bruv updating now, Have a good one, cheerios :)

Comment: @Tats_innit still not going to work !!! that will get the contents

Comment: @ManseUK `.value` bruv ? or you nailed it with `attr("value")`:P

Comment: @Tats_innit `$('#example') .text or .html` will not work ... this will get the contents of the `td` element

Comment: @ManseUK yep bruv, was not able to edit the comment hence added a new one, Thanks bruv for your explanation though, have a nice one B-) , cheerios!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! :) I already found a solution. I just wrote the value in between the td tags and hide it using css and then I accessed it using .text :)

Answer (score 3):

TDs don't have a value attribute. Using jQuery, you **could** access it via `$('example').attr('value')`, but this is wrong. In HTML5 you could use a `data-value` attribute which is all legal.

Comment: I don't think you can just access `document.getElementById('example').value`. Arbitrary attributes are **not** converted to properties (why should they?). The DOM interface is clearly defined. At least it does not work in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/tS8XY/. You'd have to use `getAttribute`.

Comment: Oh you are right, I always thought this was possible. Thanks for that comment.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#example').attr('value');
```

although using the `value` attribute on a `td` isnt valid HTML ... [Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/hRnq7/) .. you should store arbitrary data on a DOM element using the `data-<name>` attribute - [see here](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/)

[This uses .attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to get the `value` attribute from your element

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById( 'example' ).getAttribute( 'value' )
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ralt/MmaMa/

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the value:

```
document.getElementById('example').firstChild.nodeValue
```

Comment: OP is talking about the value of the `value` attribute, not the inner text.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all of your answers! :D But I found another solution: I put the value in between the td tags and hid it using the css. I get the value using .text in Javascript.